# Как зациклить программу в С++?

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как зациклить программу, чтобы при попытке набрать другой символ выдавалось сообщение с ошибкой и происходило возвращение в начало программы?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    float ctemp, ftemp;
    cout << "Najmite 1 dlya perevoda shkali Celsiya " << endl;
    cout << "v shkaly Farengei'ta. " << endl;
    cout << "Najmite 2 dlya perevoda shkali Farengei'ta " << endl;
    cout << "v shkaly Celsiya: ";
    cin >> n;

    if (n == 1) {
        cout << "Vvedite temperatyry v 'C': ";
        cin >> ctemp;

        ftemp = ctemp * 9 / 5 + 32;

        cout << "temperatura po farengei'ty: " << ftemp << endl;
    } else if (n == 2) {
        cout << "Vvedite temperatyry v 'F': ";
        cin >> ftemp;

        ctemp = (ftemp - 32) * 5 / 9;

        cout << "temperatura po celsiyu: " << ctemp << endl;
    } else {

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while (true) {
        int n;

        cin >> n;
        if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
            // Выполнить то, что нужно

            break;
        }

        cout << "Ошибка" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте цикл while() + [switch()](http://www.cyberguru.ru/programming/cpp/cpp-programming-guide-page43.html)